# Browser with find regex support

Tags: osx, web-browser

Is there a good browser with regex and javascript support? Sometimes I have to search stuff using regex [image: Doesn't search for regex :(]

Comment: Instead of a completely new browser I would look for an extension to your current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only browser with native support for Regex searches I was able to find is [**Konqueror**](https://apps.kde.org/en/konqueror). It's available onley for Linux systems.

You should rely on a plugin, for example:

- [**Chrome Regex Search**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-regex-search/bpelaihoicobbkgmhcbikncnpacdbknn) extension for Google Chrome
- *found nothing* for Safari
- [**Regex Search**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/regexsearch/) add-on for Mozilla Firefox

You can use RegEx search in Google Chrome DevTools, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on Mac, but it will search in the code and not for the page content only.